# What is the correct syntax for calling a generic function that generates a publisher?

Tags: swift, combine

What is the correct syntax of calling the following fetchURL function?

```
func fetchURL<T: Decodable>(_ url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> {
     URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
    .map(\.data)
    .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

I'm confused here.

```
let url = URL(string:"http://apple.com")
let publisher = fetchURL<[String].self>(url)????
```

Comment: I tried both 'publisher' formats.  The short-format gave me a compiled error.   The long-format appears to be okay.

Comment: You shouldn't edit answers with errors, if something didn't work; just use comments. My answer gives you two *alternative* approaches. The error you're seeing is because you're using a second approach without actually changing the function signature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't call a generic function by specifying its concrete type directly as you would, for example, with a `struct` - Swift needs to infer it.

Since `T` only appears in the return value, Swift can only infer its type based on the type that you're assigning the return value to, so you need to be explicit about it:

```
let publisher: AnyPublisher<[String], Error> = fetchURL(url)
```

This is rather inconvenient, so a better approach is to add a Type parameter as a function's argument, which Swift would now use to infer the concrete type `T`:

```
func fetchURL<T: Decodable>(_ t: T.Type, url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> {
   // ...
}

let publisher = fetchURL([String].self, url: url)
```

<sup>For example, [`JSONDecoder.decode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/2895189-decode) uses the same approach</sup>

---

As suggested in comments, you can also specify a default value for the type, so you could omit it if the type can be otherwise inferred:

```
func fetchURL<T: Decodable>(_ t: T.Type = T.self, url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> {
   // ...
}

let pub1: AnyPublisher<[String], Error> = fetchURL(url: url)
let pub2 = fetchURL([String].self, url: url)
```

Comment: You can also specify a default for the `type` parameter. Then the compiler can infer the type when possible, and you can specify when it cannot be inferred. `func fetchURL<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type = T.self, url: URL)`

Comment: Although your answer is perfect, `JSONDecoder.decode`'s approach is terrible.