# Defining type of optional generic closure parameter

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I want to create an interface, that can be invoked with a generic and a non generic parameter used in the `Result` type.

The API would look like the following:

```
struct NonGenericParameter {}

func taskPreparation<T: Decodable>(onTypedComplete: ((Result<T, Error>) -> Void)?, 
                                   onTyplessComplete: ((Result<NonGenericParameter, Error>) -> Void)?) {
    // Do the neccessery preparation...
    
    if let onComplete = onTypedComplete {
        task(onComplete: onComplete)
    }
    
    if let onComplete = onTyplessComplete {
        task(onComplete: onComplete)
    }
}

func task<T: Decodable>(onComplete: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
    // do task...
}

func task(onComplete: @escaping (Result<NonGenericParameter, Error>) -> Void) {
    // do task...
}
```

However, when i try to invoke the `taskPreparation` API, specifying `onTyplessComplete` as `nil`

```
taskPreparation(onTypedComplete: nil, 
                onTyplessComplete: { result in // Do something ... })
```

I receive the error

> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred.

I understand, i have to specify the type of the generic parameter. I have tried to create a dummy decodable parameter, and pass it to the closure.

```
struct DummyDecodable: Decodable {}
taskPreparation(onTypedComplete: { (result: Result<DummyDecodable, Error>) in },
                onTyplessComplete: { result in // Do something ... })
```

But obviously, in this case the `onTypedComplete` closure is not `nil`.

Does someone have an idea how could I specify a `nil` closure and satisfy the type inference too?

Comment: You can use the approach in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64230704/968155) to specify the type explicitly.

Comment: @NewDev thanks for the link, but your suggestion has the same issue. 
`nil` can not be inferred.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mean that it could be inferred - I just meant that you could use a parameter to help infer `T`...

Comment: Aren't the method `taskPreparation()` etc, on a specific protocol/struct/class? Wouldn't it be inferred "before hand"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would still need the `DummyDecodable` for this, which is kind of ugly, but at least you are passing a `nil` value:

Simply pass `((Result<DummyDecodable, Error>) -> Void)?.none`. `nil` is in fact just a syntactic sugar for `Optional<WhateverType>.none`.

```
struct DummyDecodable: Decodable {}
taskPreparation(onTypedComplete: ((Result<DummyDecodable, Error>) -> Void)?.none,
                onTyplessComplete: { result in /* Do something ...*/ })
```